# Git merge with master without checkout to master

Tags: git, version-control

Every time I need to `merge` `develop` with `master` I do:

`git checkout master`

`git merge develop`

Sometimes I forget to switch out of `master`. Due to this, I mistakenly make changes to code while still on `master`. It can be messy. I've committed to `master` a few times by mistake.

Is there a way to `merge` to `master` without switching first to `master`?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to do a *real* merge into master, no.  A real merge needs, at least potentially, a work-tree in which to do work.  It also uses the index, which needs to match the current branch around the outside of the operation (see `git worktree add` method below).

If you want to do a *fast-forward* operation (not an actual merge), it is possible.  For instance:

```
git push . develop:master
```

(note the lack of `+` sign or `--force` option) will attempt to fast-forward your `master` to the same commit as your `develop`.  Use `HEAD` to mean the current branch:

```
git push . HEAD:master
```

These only work if the fast-forward is possible.  If not, you will get an error of the form:

```
 ! [rejected]              [name] -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

which tells you that you need a work-tree whose branch is `master` in which to run `git merge`.

To do that without changing the branch of your *current* work-tree, use `git worktree add`, if your Git is at least 2.5 (preferably at least 2.15).  For instance, suppose you are in the top level of your repository, on branch `feature/X`:

```
git worktree add ../master   # NB: assumes ../master is available as a directory name
cd ../master
git merge feature/X
...                 # do what it takes to complete the merge here

cd -                # return to your main repository
rm -rf ../master    # remove added worktree
git worktree prune  # clean up list of added worktrees
```

The added work-tree has its own index (and its own `HEAD`) so `git merge` now has an index and work-tree in which to do its job, or leave its mess for you to fix, whichever actually occurs (see [kostix's comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447800/git-merge-with-master-without-checkout-to-master/54448344?noredirect=1#comment95705408_54447966).

Comment: I would add the necessary trivia: a "real" merge without employing the work tree (the checkout) is impossible simply due to the reason a true merge might result in merge conflict which require 1) special setup of the staging area; 2) inserting conflict markers into relevant files; 3) _human interaction_ to resolve the conflicts and crafting the state of the index ready to be committed — to finalize the merge.

Comment: Great Post - love the details. `git push . HEAD:master` will be my new fav command. For reference, if anyone wants another way of saying the same thing, this blog shows a few more examples of how to do fast-forward "commits", without changing branches: https://samuelgruetter.net/blog/2018/08/31/git-ffwd-without-checkout/ This post combined with that blog clarified, to me, how to use this command variation.

Comment: What does the dot `.` mean in that `git push` expression?

Comment: @matt: `.` is treated as a file-path so it means "the current repository".

Comment: And it's what we're pushing to?

Comment: @matt: Yes. We're invoking Git on ourself, sending ourself any commits we don't have (obviously we have all the commits that we have so this never sends any commits), then asking ourself to please, if it's OK (i.e., if it's a fast-forward), set the given branch name (RHS of refspec) to the given commit (LHS of refspec after passing through rev-parse or equivalent).

Comment: @torek do you think [git-forward-merge](https://github.com/schuyler1d/git-forward-merge) is valid option?

Comment: @BernardoDalCorno: at a quick glance, that script looks reasonably well written, and seems to do what it says in the documentation. It could probably be improved some by assuming a modern (2.15+) Git with fully functional `git worktree`, and/or integrated into a standard Git distribution, but as long as you know what you're doing with it, it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

No.

I suppose you could write a small shell script to do the three steps:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
git checkout master
git merge develop
git checkout develop
```

You might also want to add a `git push origin master` before the last checkout.

Answer (score 1):

You may give a try to a command called [`git graft`](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-graft) provide by [`git-extras`](https://github.com/tj/git-extras).

It is not properly a git command, but `git-extras` provides a bunch of tools for working with git repositories.

In your case **`git graft develop master`** may give you the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

git alias that merges the current branch to master and returns to the current branch:

```
git config alias.merge2master '!curbr=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && git checkout master && git merge $curbr && git checkout -'
```

Call it as `git merge2master`.

To make it completely parametrized:

```
git config alias.merge-to '!f() { !curbr=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && destbr="{$1:-master}" && git checkout $destbr && git merge $curbr && git checkout -; }; f'
```

Call it `git merge-to` or `git merge-to somebranch`. Default is `master`

Comment: Note that you can also use `git checkout -` to switch back.

Comment: Yep, thanx! Doesn't buy much as I have to calcualte `curbr` anyway.