# Can I merge two branches when I am in another branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-commit

Suppose I am in branch A. How can I merge branches B and C without checking out another branch?

Can I use this command?
`git merge B C`

Comment: Is there any reason to do this? Why not `commit` or `stash` your changes on A then  `checkout` the branch you want to merge to?

Comment: @syoung No, I just want to learn.

Comment: I think it's idiomatic and standard practice to use `checkout`, but these threads might suffice. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447800/git-merge-with-master-without-checkout-to-master) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777629/merge-branches-without-checking-out-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.... you can't. For these cases, you can use *temporarily* a new worktree:

```
git worktree add blahblah B
cd blahblah
git merge C
cd ..
git worktree remove blahblah
```

Comment: Or just stash and then come back to what you are doing at the time in the current worktree as is pretty customary.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I merge branches B and C without checking out another branch?

There is no such thing as merging branches B and C. Merging is *into*. You can merge B into C, or you can merge C into B. They are very different things.

Either way, you *must* be on the branch you are merging into. This is because Git needs to use the working tree to enact the merge.

Comment: For what the working tree is and how switching branches relates to it, see my   https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/  For more about what Git merge is, see my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/.